# {$taxonomy}_edit_form_fields not working

Tags: custom-taxonomy

In my plugin file, I'm trying to add content to the screen where custom taxonomy of custom post type is edited. Unfortunatelly nothing appears...

```
<?
// A callback function to add a custom field to our taxonomy  
function my_custom_fields() {  
?>
<tr class="form-field">  
    <td>  
        hello 
    </td>  
</tr>  
<?
}  

// Add the fields to the taxonomy, using our callback function  
add_action( 'tha-seminar-category_edit_form_fields', 'my_custom_fields', 10, 2 );  
?>
```

This is how I register the taxonomy:

```
register_taxonomy('tha-seminar-category', 'tha_seminars',
array("hierarchical" => true,
"label" => "Tha Seminar Categories",
'update_count_callback' => '_update_post_term_count',
'query_var' => true,
'public' => true,
'show_ui' => true,
'show_admin_column' => true,
'show_tagcloud' => true,
'_builtin' => false,
'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
'show_in_rest' => true,
'show_in_quick_edit' => true,
'capabilities' => array(
    'manage_terms' => 'edit_tha_seminars',
    'edit_terms' => 'edit_tha_seminars',
    'delete_terms' => 'edit_tha_seminars',
    'assign_terms' => 'edit_tha_seminars'
    )
)
);
```

The screen I expect to see "hello" at
[image]

Thanks for help!

Comment: Your screenshot is of the _new_ term form. If you click to edit a term do you see your field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `tha-seminar-category_add_form_fields`action to show on new category page. 
`tha-seminar-category_edit_form_fields` is for the edit page of the category